# Есть ли отличие в условии PHP?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Нашел у себя в движке такое условие

```
if ( $num_data_lvl === 0 || $num_data_lvl === "0" )
```

Подскажите, а что, разве есть отличие нуля в кавычках от нуля без кавычек ?

Comment: Конечно. Без кавычек проверяется ноль как integer. С кавычками - как string. Обратите внимание, что используется оператор ===, а это значит "поле соответствие", включая тип переменной

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, то нажмите на галочку слева от ответа, который вам помог.

Answer (score 4):

Это точное сравнение. Поэтому если, например, переменная `$num_data_lvl` содержит число 0, и вы попытаетесь ее сравнить со строкой "0", то результат будет false.

Поэтому данное условие

```
if ( $num_data_lvl === 0 || $num_data_lvl === "0" )
```

проверяет, что переменная `$num_data_lvl` содержит в точности либо число 0 либо строку "0".

Answer (score 2):

А давайте проверим. Напишем код, который будет отдавать переменную на проверку.

```
$test = "0";

if ($test===0)  {echo "test is int\n";}
if ($test==="0"){echo "test is string\n";}
```

Если разницы нет, то на экран выведется

```
test is int
test is string
```

Выполняем код и видим, что вывелось только

```
test is string
```

Если изменим `$test = 0;`, то выведется

```
test is int
```

Выходит, что разница есть. С кавычками это сравнение строк, а без них - чисел.